# Remove method from IList interface not recognized when I try to call it from an Array object

Tags: c#, arrays, interface

According to the official [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/#array-overview), arrays in C# implement the following interfaces:

- `IList`
- `IEnumerable`

In the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ilist?view=net-6.0#methods) for `IList`, I see that one of the listed methods is a `Remove` method which does the following:

> Removes the first occurrence of a specific object from the IList.

I wanted to use this method, so I wrote the following minimal program:

```
class RemoveAllOccurences {

    static void Main() 
    {
        int[] a = {1, 0, 0, 3};
        
        a.Remove(0);

    }
}
```

I then compiled with the following:

`csc test.cs -out:test.exe`

Running the executable threw the following error:

> remove_issue.cs(7,11): error CS1061: 'int[]' does not contain a definition for 'Remove' and no accessible extension method 'Remove' accepting a first argument of type 'int[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I'm not sure why `Remove` is not recognized, since as I mentioned before it is part of the `IList` interface shown in the docs.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arrays implement `IList.Remove` via [*explicit interface implementation*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation), which means you can only access it via a reference with a compile-time type of the interface type. So for example:

```cs
int[] a = {1, 0, 0, 3};
IList list = a;
list.Remove(0);
```

That *compiles* with no problem. However, it will then throw an exception (`NotSupportedException`) at execution time because arrays are of fixed size - `Remove` and `Add` operations don't make sense on them. That's why those methods are implemented with explicit interface implementation, to avoid you using them inappropriately...

Comment: So basically it implements an interface, but then doesn't support its functions? Why does it implement the interface then?

Comment: Because the indexer feature is also coming from IList and you want that for an Array. You may ask why its just one interface for that and not two distinct interfaces but the answer then would be presumably be something along the line of history, not wanting to break stuff, keeping it simple etc.